# How to store and retrieve all varieties of REST server responses in mongodb efficiently and correctly

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, httpresponse

Consider a scenario where MongoDB is used to save responses sent by RESTful servers. The information got as response from a server is captured as a [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) object. What is the best way to store and retrieve this response, taking the criteria mentioned below into consideration?

1. The application should be as generic as possible, supporting efficient storage and retrieval of various types of server responses like JSON, XML, and whatever there might be.
2. The response bodies, in whatever format they may be, must be editable in the application.
3. The responses can be from hundreds of different ReST API servers like Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, Google Analytics, Zoho, etc.
4. Responses are to be saved only when HTTP status is `200 OK`.

This is how a typical response looks like when converted to string:

```
<200,{birthday=10/30/1995, security_settings={secure_browsing= 
{enabled=true}}, favorite_athletes=[{id=556787781118967, name=Kawai 
Leonard}], favorite_teams=[{id=25781101980, name=San Antonio Spurs}], 
id=12743794760832},{ETag=["7ac095dba856fe41a3f2d783"], Strict-Transport- 
Security=[max-age=15552000; preload], x-fb-trace-id=[DGINCEt], x-fb-rev= 
[4318280], x-app-usage=[{"call_count":0,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":0}], 
Expires=[Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT], Content-Type=[application/json; 
charset=UTF-8], facebook-api-version=[v2.0], Cache-Control=[private, no- 
cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Access-Control-Allow- 
Origin=[*], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], X-FB-Debug= 
[6ZufD3aKzLBGVFuxVL9w+PWkiMtV7ee6vUBjqVsz2VgE75OkHeFEbZmc9Uw==], Date=[Wed, 
12 Sep 2018 16:52:57 GMT], Connection=[keep-alive]}>
```

Breaking it down, the response has:

1. [HttpStatus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html)
2. Response body in a format specified in the response headers
3. [MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) of headers.

As per the current implementation, the response got from the server is picked as a `ResponseEntity<String>` object, and while storing, body and headers are separated out. The body is extracted from `ResponseEntity<String>` object as a `String` and saved as it is in MongoDB. It facilitates simple modifications on the string too.
The header too, extracted from the `ResponseEntity` object as a [HttpHeaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html) object, is stored using `Object` datatype in MongoDB.

As part of extracting responses, the headers and the body are retrieved separately from the database, and `ResponseEntity<String>` object is [constructed](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ResponseEntity-T-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-org.springframework.http.HttpStatus-) using them along with [HttpStatus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html).

Are there any flaws in the above implementation? Any REST server behaviour that should be taken care of while dealing with its response, for which the above implementation will not work? Any suggestions on how to increase the robustness and efficiency of this functionality of the web app?

Comment: In general I would say make it a json-object. If you look at the structure its very much like a dictionary with key value pairs. Sometimes the value is another dict. That is basicly json. mongodb's syntax was made to be json like aswell.

Comment: As `ResponseEntity` is not a Spring-Data-MongoDB entity you either need to convert it manually to a `@Document(collection="...")` annotated S-D-MDb entity or try [custom converters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters). I've only used custom converters for MongoDB entities so far tough and hence can't state if it works with other objects as well.